# Parse minified XML string in R

Tags: xml, r, analytics

I want to print minified xml string in tree format using R,

*I have written following code :*

```
> ex  <- "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"
> 
> XML::xmlParse(ex)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and it works fine but if i try this example for other XML string like :

```
ex2 <- "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "Foo.dtd"><a><b>bbb</b><c/><d><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://xxx" xmlns:xsd="http://yyy" xmlns:xsi="http://zzz"></soapenv></d><e><![CDATA[ <z></z> ]]></e><f><g></g></f></a>"
**Error: unexpected numeric constant in "ex2 <- "<?xml version="1.0"**
```

Please suggest how can i make this work.

I need the result like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "Foo.dtd">
<a>
    <b>bbb</b>
    <c/>
    <d>
        <soapenv:Envelope 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://xxx" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://yyy" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://zzz">
        </soapenv>
    </d>
    <e>
        <![CDATA[ <z></z> ]]>
    </e>
    <f>
        <g></g>
    </f>
</a>
```

Please suggest the property that can be applied to ignore Tag mismatch..!

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description></book><book id="bk102"><author>Ralls, Kim</author><title>Midnight Rain</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date><description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description></book><book id="bk103"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Maeve Ascendant</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date><description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description></book><book id="bk104"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>Oberon's Legacy</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date><description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description></book><book id="bk105"><author>Corets, Eva</author><title>The Sundered Grail</title><genre>Fantasy</genre><price>5.95</price><publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date><description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description></book><book id="bk106"><author>Randall, Cynthia</author><title>Lover Birds</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date><description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description></book><book id="bk107"><author>Thurman, Paula</author><title>Splish Splash</title><genre>Romance</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description></book><book id="bk108"><author>Knorr, Stefan</author><title>Creepy Crawlies</title><genre>Horror</genre><price>4.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date><description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description></book><book id="bk109"><author>Kress, Peter</author><title>Paradox Lost</title><genre>Science Fiction</genre><price>6.95</price><publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date><description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description></book><book id="bk110"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date><description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description></book><book id="bk111"><author>O'Brien, Tim</author><title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>36.95</price><publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date><description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description></book><book id="bk112"><author>Galos, Mike</author><title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>49.95</price><publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date><description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description></book></catalog>
```

Comment: Did you try with simple quote inside the double quote? Or to replace " by \"" inside your border double quote?

Comment: @YCR : "head slap my self", variable got assigned but now i am getting the below error: XML::xmlParse(ex2)
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Envelope line 1 and soapenv
Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: Envelope line 1 and soapenv

Answer (score 0):

```
ex2 <- "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM 'Foo.dtd'><a><b>bbb</b><c/><d><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://xxx' xmlns:xsd='http://yyy' xmlns:xsi='http://zzz'></soapenv:Envelope></d><e><![CDATA[ <z></z> ]]></e><f><g></g></f></a>"

XML::xmlParse(ex2)
```

replace /soapenv by /soapenv:Envelope.

The error message is self explainable.

Comment: thanks for your help, can you also suggest if there is a property that can ignore mismatch of the tags.

Comment: Hey YRC, your solution is not working for my actual XML, it contains many double quotes, please help with a work around.

Comment: Nice one to look after. I don't see an easy option to deal with it. The harsh way I see to do it is to parse it as an html, with htmlTreeParse and to manually find the informations you are interested in.

Comment: Could you edit your post to add a reproducible example?

Comment: I have attached a sample XML file, please advise.